# Fix "warning: output has a corrupt string table index"

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to write an ELF linkable to a file, but objdump and ld always give the following warning: "output has a corrupt string table index". objdump can't get the assembled code and after using ld it doesn't execute anything. I've tried messing with the size, offset, and string index values to no success. I've also tried searching for a solution and couldn't find anything.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <elf.h>

int main() {
    // ELF header
    Elf64_Ehdr ELFheader;

    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_MAG0] = ELFMAG0; // Magic shit
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_MAG1] = ELFMAG1;
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_MAG2] = ELFMAG2;
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_MAG3] = ELFMAG3;
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_CLASS] = ELFCLASS64; // 64 bit
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_DATA] = ELFDATA2LSB; // Little edain
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_VERSION] = EV_CURRENT; // Current ELF version
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_OSABI] = ELFOSABI_SYSV; // System V
    ELFheader.e_ident[EI_ABIVERSION] = 0;
    
    ELFheader.e_type = ET_REL;
    ELFheader.e_machine = EM_X86_64; // AMD x86
    ELFheader.e_version = EV_CURRENT;
    ELFheader.e_entry = 0;
    ELFheader.e_phoff = 0;
    ELFheader.e_shoff = 64; // Sections start 64 bytes in the file
    ELFheader.e_flags = 0;
    ELFheader.e_ehsize = 64; // Header size
    ELFheader.e_phentsize = 0; // Program header size
    ELFheader.e_phnum = 0; // Number of program headers
    ELFheader.e_shentsize = 64;
    ELFheader.e_shnum = 1; // 2 Section headers
    ELFheader.e_shstrndx = 1;

    // Section header
    Elf64_Shdr TextSection;
    TextSection.sh_name = DT_TEXTREL; // .text
    TextSection.sh_type = SHT_PROGBITS;
    TextSection.sh_flags = SHF_EXECINSTR;
    TextSection.sh_addr = 0;
    TextSection.sh_offset = 128;
    TextSection.sh_size = 13;
    TextSection.sh_link = 0;
    TextSection.sh_info = 0;
    TextSection.sh_addralign = 16;
    TextSection.sh_entsize = 0; // Section header index

    unsigned char code[13] = "\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05"; // Code, exits with a syscall


    {
        FILE *fout = fopen("output", "w");
        fwrite(&ELFheader, sizeof(ELFheader), 1, fout);
        fclose(fout);
    }
    {
        FILE *fout = fopen("output", "a");
        fwrite(&TextSection, sizeof(TextSection), 1, fout);
        fclose(fout);
    }
    {
        FILE *fout = fopen("output", "a");
        fwrite(&code, 13, 1, fout);
        fclose(fout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How would you fix this?

Comment: Please post the full exact error message verbatim from `objdump`. https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/bb608f811bcd013cf7f8b8038310f169639f29d5/bfd/elfcode.h#L763 - `i_ehdrp->e_shstrndx >= elf_numsections (abfd)` - maybe `ELFheader.e_shstrndx = 0;`?

Comment: I still get the same error, and objdump didn't output anything.

Answer (score 1):

`DT_TEXTREL` is definitely not a section name, or an index thereof. You need to actually store section name in your file and reference it in `sh_name`.

Comment: In addition, an `ET_REL` file _must_ have `.strtab` and `.symtab` sections to be useful for subsequent linking.